# plot two sets of data by using a class

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am a very beginner in Python, so I don't know the technical reasons of the bug, and probably I will miss something in the request.

I am trying to plot two different sets of data on the same plot, but there is something wrong in my code.
The purpose is to plot "pulse profiles", eg, count rate versus the phase, and on the same plot also the results from some fitting analysis for a spectra analyses in the same phase bin.
I am using `twinx(`) because the y axis has two different scales.
However, I have to call a class in the main code, and this class is necessary to read the data from some given text files.
When I try to plot different data, simply created with standard function directly in the code, like in the official example [here](http://matplotlib.org/faq/howto_faq.html#multiple-y-axis-scales) then no problems come out.
I will post my code, hoping that the complication with the class will not prevent from a good understanding of the subject:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
 
import glob, re, sys, os
sys.path.append('/path-to-the-class-file/')
 
from scipy import *
from pylab import *
from prs import *
from scipy import optimize
from scipy import stats
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pyfits
           
#--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------#      
# *data* is the class that read the data
 
data=Data('1131', array(['0.0_0.10','0.10_0.24','0.24_0.40','0.40_0.60','0.60_0.83','0.83_1.0']), array(['0.0_0.10','0.10_0.24','0.24_0.40','0.40_0.60','0.60_0.83','0.83_1.0']), 8, 3)
 
pp=pyfits.open('/path-to-the-fits-file-with-the-data/')
phase = pp[1].data.field(0)
rate = pp[1].data.field(2)
pp.close()
 
ax1 = subplot(311)
ax1.plot(phase, rate)
ay1 = ax1.twinx()
 
ecyc=data.ecyc1
ay1.plot(phase, ecyc)
```

I have not specified anything about the class because I am not sure it is useful.
The error that I receive is the follow:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "prs2.py", line 36, in <module>
    ay1.plot(phase, ecyc) #, yerr = (demin, demax))
  File "/science/epd-7.1-2-rh5-x86_64/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/axes.py", line 3783, in plot
    for line in self._get_lines(*args, **kwargs):
  File "/science/epd-7.1-2-rh5-x86_64/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/axes.py", line 317, in _grab_next_args
    for seg in self._plot_args(remaining, kwargs):
  File "/science/epd-7.1-2-rh5-x86_64/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/axes.py", line 294, in _plot_args
    x, y = self._xy_from_xy(x, y)
  File "/science/epd-7.1-2-rh5-x86_64/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/axes.py", line 234, in _xy_from_xy
    raise ValueError("x and y must have same first dimension")
ValueError: x and y must have same first dimension
```

pr2.py is the name of the main file.

I hope I have posted according to the rules.
Any suggestion please?

Comment: It looks like `phase` and `ecyc` do not have the same first dimension.  Check the shapes of these arrays.

Comment: In concordance with Warren's comment, `ecyc` is probably not a one-dimensional array. This depends on the definition of `Data` though, and we have no way of finding that out (I'm guessing it comes from the module `prs`, which may be a home-grown module. Also, note the danger here on wildcards imports. Something like `from prs import Data` would have been better and clearer).